# HIbernate criteria multiple entity

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

How can I turn the HQL query

```
select t1, t2 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 where ....
```

in  a query with criteria?

I want you to give me back an Object [] with the entity

Thanks.

Sergio

Comment: Is there any relationship between t1 and t2 ? if exists can u post here

Comment: t1 and t2 have a relation ManyToMany but I want to extract the two entities to be able to paging properly.